# Hdfs data corruption issue

Tags: hive, hdfs, hiveql, hortonworks-data-platform

we have a data corruption issue at our hadoop cluster. We have a managed table on hive which contains three years of data partitioned by year.

Below two queries run fine without any issue

```
select count(*) from tkt_hist table where yr=2015

select count(*) from tkt_hist table where yr=2016

select count(*) from tkt_hist table where yr=2017
```

However, when we try to do group by per year, below error is shown.

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException java.io.FileNotFoundException: File hdfs://ASIACELLHDP/apps/hive/warehouse/gprod1t_base.db/toll_tkt_hist_old/yr=2015/mn=01/dy=01 does not exist. [ERROR_STATUS]
```

Even select will not work when we specify a year other than  2015.

```
//this works fine
Select * from tkt_hist where yr=2015 limit 10;

// below throws same  error mentioned above.
Select * from tkt_hist where yr=2016;
```

Comment: It seems that physical partition does not exist but partition exists in metastore: Use these command to repair the table:   msck repair table mytable;

Comment: Is it safe to execute this command? its actually production data. The thing which lead to this issue was that we accidentally created another managed table in the same hdfs folder where the effected table was created.

Comment: This command will create a physical directory for all the missing partition. In other word some of partition information is available in metastore but the actually partition path is not present. Then it will just create the partition file path. Thats all.  So I think its safe.

Comment: Did you check in the hdfs ? For the files that you are getting error ?

Comment: what hive version are u using?

Comment: @hlagos hive version is Hive 1.2.1.2.3.4.0-3485

Comment: @KKK repairing table did not work. It seems physical partitions got deleted which means data is not available any more on hdfs somehow.

Comment: `msck repair table` will not work. It can add partitions, but won't remove them from the metastore if the directories in HDFS don't exist. You have to drop the partitions manually. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing java heap space (increase reducer memory if it doesn't work).

For example:

```
set mapreduce.map.java.opts = -Xmx15360m
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to drop the partitions manually because `msck repair table` only adds partitions but doesn't remove existing ones.

You will have to iterate through the corrupt partitions list. For internal tables, you'll have to be specific, as dropping a partition deletes the underlying physical files.

`ALTER TABLE tkt_hist DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(yr=2015, mn=01, dy=01);`

You will need to do this for each partition. You could put it in a bash script and execute it with `hive -e` or `beeline -e` commands to work with a quoted query string.

If you are using an external table, then it's much easier to remove all partitions and then repair table.

`ALTER TABLE tkt_hist DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(yr<>'', mn<>'', dy<>'');`

Make sure to repair the table as the user owning the Hive DB as well as the HDFS path.

`MSCK REPAIR TABLE tkt_hist;`

This should add partitions folders currently available in the table path without adding the invalid partitions.

Note: If your user isn't the owner of the directory, ensure you have write permissions and do your work in the `hive` access client as `beeline` requires absolute ownership rights to work.